# Getting visible area of Image in React Native ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, zooming, crop

I have a scrollView with a single Image in it. Initially the Image has the same width & heigth as the ScrollView.

I am trying to crop this image based on how the user have zoomed and moved the image. Basically, I want to know what part of the image is visible, so that I can crop it accordingly.

Im using expo's ImageManipulator to crop it, so I have that part covered. But to get the dimensions of what part of the Image is visible after zoom/drag is whats bugging me.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is to first fill the `Image` component inside the size of the `ScrollView`. This way, the size of the image will be equal to the size of the `ScrollView`.

First, you need to set `directionalLockEnabled` prop to `false` and `horizontal` prop to `true` to make the `ScrollView` scroll horizontally.

Then, set `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` props to make your `ScrollView` zoomable. Now, every time you zoom and scroll in your `ScrollView` it will fire `onMomentumScrollEnd` and `onScrollEndDrag` with the `event` parameter from which you can get the visible part of your `ScrollView` which is usually,

1. `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset`
2. `event.nativeEvent.contentSize`
3. `event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement`

Since your `Image` Component size is same as that of the `ScrollView` Component, it will give you the exact visible area of the image in the `ScrollView`.

For Detailed implementation example, you can refer to [this file](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-editor/blob/master/example/src/App.js) of the [react-native-community/react-native-image-editor](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-editor) repository